# How to patch a record based on selected value in PowerApps?

Tags: excel, patch, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

My `DataSource` is Excel file.I have gallery which consists of different Reference #'s, which `On-click` navigates the user to `Update Status` screen.

**The `Update Status` Screen has the following Datacards:**

- "Cancel Reservation"
- "Cancel Reason"
- "Current Status"
- "Steps"

I used the `Visible` property of Datacard such that when user Selects "Y" from "Cancel Reservation", it displays to them "Cancel Reason" and "Current Status" datacard.

Similarly, when "N" is selected it displays them "Current Status" and "Steps" datacard.

The Update Status screen consists of Submit button. The `On-Select` property of the Submit button is set to `Submitform(form1)`.

**Issue:** When "N" is selected from "Cancel Reservation", "Cancel Reason" data is getting updated along with "Current Status" and "Steps" datacard.

I am new to PowerApps and wondering if there a way to update "Cancel Reason" and "Current Status" when "Y" is selected. Likewise, when "N" is selected it shud only update "Current Status" and "Steps"?

**Note:** "Cancel Reason","Update Status" consists of dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional branching of Form controls can sometimes be tricky. The key for you is going to be the `Default` and maybe the `Update` property of each Datacard.

I imagine when user clicks the Reference # in the initial Gallery, you're setting `NewForm(form1)`. This means the `Default` property of each dropdown is likely `Parent.Default`.

Experiment with setting these conditionally, similar to how you have `Visibility` set.

**Example:**

- Set the `Default` property for "Current Status" and "Steps" Datacards to something like:

```
If(
    ddCancelReservation.Selected.Value = "N",
    "N/A"
)
```

Do something similar for the other cards. You can also mess with the `Update` property to control what data is written to the Sharepoint list.